# Did any of TOS 5 year mission first contacts aliens show up in later Star Trek episodes as Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-enterprise

Are there any examples of Star Trek TOS aliens being assimulated by the Borg in any of the following versions of the Star Trek TV/Movie franchise? [image: Aliens]

Comment: Mmmm. Gorn Borg.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By the standards set forth in the question, there are 55 original series species that are "encountered/discovered" during TOS Star Trek. Of those 55 species, only the Romulans meet the criteria of

- having been discovered or encountered during "first contact" during the TOS Star Trek.
- having had members of their species assimilated by the Borg.

[image: enter link description here]

I put quotations around first contact since the Federation had been at War with the Romulans before TOS but had not communicated (beyond trying to blow up their ships) before the 1966 episode of TOS called "Balance of Terror" first aired on September 13, 1966 and was the 14th episode of Star Trek to be aired.

The Romulans are identified by the Borg as Species 3783.

[List of Star Trek Races](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_races)

Comment: Again, the title of this post asks for "First Contact" aliens from TOS.  I don't believe any of these really fit the bill.

Comment: Cardassians was TNG (along with Ferengi, one of 7s personality shifts in VOY:Infinite Regress)? And the rest are all in ENT, which is a prequel to TOS.

Comment: @Iszi Romulans are the only ones that fit both criteria.  While technically First Contact with the Romulans was before TOS, no member of the Federation had actually _seen_ a Romulan until the events of TOS.

Comment: My thoughts exactly Izkata.

Comment: Good edit.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Thaddeus If I recall correctly, the Federation and the Romulans communicated by radio when they negotiated the treaty.  And maybe during/before the war itself.

Comment: They probably threatened each other quite effectively. But nuclear conflict probably doesn't count as an EFFECTIVE first contact scenario. At least not from the Federation's standards. Might have been just fine by the Romulan's.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you are willing to include games in the franchise, here's one [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29)

> In the Star Trek Game *Star Trek: Legacy*, the Borg are featured midway through the TOS era as "Assimilated **Klingon** ships". In the final mission, once the player has completed the primary objective, a confrontation with T'urell ensues; she departs, and the player must destroy a Borg Sphere.

Also, same [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29#Other_media) has 2 more book examples, one of a race whose creation is mentioned in TOS, and one, of an attempt to assimilate TOS's Spock:

> The Peter David novel *Vendetta* reveals that the planet killer weapon from the Original Series episode "*The Doomsday Machine*" is a prototype for a weapon against the Borg, **with a woman whose race were destroyed by the Borg** trying to use the weapon against them despite the damage she will cause on her journey due to its need to consume planets. David revisited this concept in a 2007 sequel novel, *Before Dishonor*, which features the Enterprise-E working with Spock and Seven of Nine to reactive the original planet killer to stop the Borg.

---

> In William Shatner's novel *The Return*, **Spock** is nearly assimilated by the Borg, but is saved because he mind-melded with V'ger, an earlier form of the Borg. Using the information he subconsciously acquired in the meld, Spock is able to lead a crew of Enterprise officers- consisting of the Enterprise-D senior staff, himself, Admiral McCoy, and the resurrected Kirk- in a Defiant-class ship to destroy the Borg central node, severing all branches of the collective from each other and limiting their future threat.

Answer (score 4):

We saw a couple of Klingon Borg in at least [voyager](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Infinite_Regress_%28episode%29). Klingons are definitely TOS aliens.

[image]

Comment: First contact with the Klingons happened *long* before TOS.  I think this is asking about species with which First Contact was conducted by Captain Kirk and the crew of the Enterprise.  NCC 1701, no bloody A, B, C, or D.

Comment: @Iszi: Yes, the picture is from ST8, but read the actual answer *text*. We encounter Borg in a Voyager episode, I just couldn't find a good picture of it. The question asks for occurrences in the whole franchise (including films), not just TNG!

Comment: The question is asking about Borg found throughout the whole franchise, yes.  But the Borg must be of a species with which First Contact occurred within TOS.  Klingons do not meet that condition.

Comment: @Iszi: First Contact from who's perspective? The crew or the audience?

Comment: From the perspective of Starfleet's timeline.

Comment: @Iszi: rofl​​​​ #igotthatreference.png

Comment: @bitmask: We encounter Borg in _loads_ of Voyager episodes. Borg _live on Voyager_ FFS! ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh yeah. I think I meant to write "We encounter Klingon-Borg in a Voyager episode,...". Would've made more sense. Guess I just forgot a word :)

Comment: @bitmask: Ah right. :) Incidentally, that's probably _Unimatrix Zero_: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Korok_(General)